# How can i Add morethen 2 Buttons and 1 text inside the trailing Property in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, trailing, flutter-widget

I Want to create a product cart list in my app. so I used Card Widget and Inside of it used a ListTile widget. Inside the listTile i used trailing property to create a Column to add 2 buttons and a Number, when i create those things its shows a layout error that **BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 55 PIXEL**.

Here are the codes

```
  @override
  _NewTestState createState() => _NewTestState();
}

class _NewTestState extends State<NewTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("data"),
        ),
        body: new Card(
          child: new ListTile(
            leading: new FlutterLogo(
              size: 50.0,
            ),
            title: new Text("Title"),
            subtitle: new Text("subtitle"),
            trailing: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                new Text("1"),
                new IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Please help me with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your `Column` is taller than `ListTile`'s height, and therefore, your `IconButton` is being clipped by `ListTile`. There are two options that come to my mind:

- If your `Column` is small enough, try setting the `isThreeLine` property of your `ListTile` to true, that will make `ListTile` a little taller, and it might be just what you need.
- A better, more general approach, would be to make your own `ListTile` by composing `Column`s and `Row`s. It is not hard to do really. Keep in mind that `ListTile` is intended for very specific cases. As the [ListTile class documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) states:

> If the way ListTile pads and positions its elements isn't quite what you're looking for, it's easy to create custom list items with a combination of other widgets, such as Rows and Columns.

Check the sample app from the documentation, this is the result it generates.

[image]

It might be a good starting point for what you need.

Answer (score 4):

use Row instead of Column.

```
 trailing: Row(
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
     children: ...
   )
```